# Cell-Address with an IF Statement

Tags: excel, if-statement, index-match

I've been using =Cell("address",... to error check formulas I'm making to create a database and it's been working pretty well until I tried to scale up my index match formulas with some if statements.

I've narrowed the issue down to where I believe it's working as intended as long as the first statement in the if statement is true, yet if the calculation goes past that (even if the original formula is fine and returns a value) it will come back with #VALUE!.

EDIT: To be clear, the formula used above returns values without issue when not using the CELL-ADDRESS function involved. The formula also returns values when split up outside the IF-Statement.

```
I2=Valid

=CELL("address",IF($I$2="Valid",INDEX($I$2:$J$6,MATCH($U$1,$H$2:$H$6,0),MATCH($V$1,$I$1:$J$1,0)),IF($I$2="Invalid",INDEX($I$2:$J$6,MATCH($W$1,$H$2:$H$6,0),MATCH($V$1,$I$1:$J$1,0)),"Error")))
```

$I$2 is returned in the cell

```
I2=Invalid

=IF($I$2="Valid",INDEX($I$2:$J$6,MATCH($U$1,$H$2:$H$6,0),MATCH($V$1,$I$1:$J$1,0)),IF($I$2="Invalid",INDEX($I$2:$J$6,MATCH($W$1,$H$2:$H$6,0),MATCH($V$1,$I$1:$J$1,0)),"Error"))
```

#VALUE! is returned

Can anyone offer a fix for this or explain why it's happening and how to avoid it?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't have time to look at your code, but I will say a couple of things: 1) "#VALUE" means that you have an error in your code. 2) If we trace through the if statements, I would assume the error has to do with : "INDEX($I$2:$J$6,MATCH($W$1,$H$2:$H$6,0),MATCH($V$1,$I$1:$J$1,0))"

Comment: 3) Try the above code by itself without an IF statement and see if you still get the error, if you do, then you need to fix it by narrowing down what is causing the issue.

Comment: As I said above, the code works fine with and without the IF statement. The code works fine without the CELL-ADDRESS function and returns a value in the cell I'm trying to test.

The problem is coming from (and I don't know why) the IF statement within CELL-ADDRESS.

IF-Statement 1 True, no problem, value returned
IF-Statement 1 False, no problem, value returned

CELL-ADDRESS IF-Statement 1 true, no problem, value returned
CELL-ADDRESS IF-Statement 1 false, #VALUE!

Comment: Are you sure that `I2` contains "Invalid" when you get a `#VALUE!` error? Perhaps it looks like it contains "Invalid", but contains an additional spacing character, for example. Check with the formula `=I2="Invalid"`. I would suspect rather than you get that error because `I2` contains neither "Valid" not "Invalid", and so the `value_if_false` clause of your second statement, i.e. "Error", is the value being passed to the `CELL` function, which clearly will return `#VALUE!`

Comment: does `=IF($I$2="Valid",CELL("address",INDEX($I$2:$J$6,MATCH($U$1,$H$2:$H$6,0),MATCH($V$1,$I$1:$J$1,0))),IF($I$2="Invalid",CELL("address",INDEX($I$2:$J$6,MATCH($W$1,$H$2:$H$6,0),MATCH($V$1,$I$1:$J$1,0))),"Error"))` work ?

Comment: Yes that's making it work now!

Interesting way to go about doing that, having two address statements built in, but if it's working it's working and I'm not one to complain.

Thank you so much for the assistance everyone and the advice.